# Using "named" parameters in function call

Tags: php, function

Unfortunately PHP does not support named parameters, but I've noticed that the PHP syntax allows us something similar:

```
function list_items( $user, $archived ) { ... }

// This is the default way to call the function.
// It's not very clear what the value and false refer to:
list_items( 10, false );

// Alternative syntax I found which makes this more clear:
list_items( $user = 10, $archived = false );
```

Both function calls return the same data.

**Question**

- Any information on the actual difference between both calls?
- Is it a good idea to use the second kind of syntax or will it cause issues?
- Is that second syntax supported in any PHP 5.x version?

Comment: You just assign the value to a variable before you call the function.

Comment: Well ... you are initializing a variable there. If you `var_dump` `$user` or `$archived`, they will have the values given in the function call.

Comment: There's a minor performance overhead of the assignments, and most of the time it will achieve the same thing with any arguments that are "pass by value" scalars; but watch out for "pass by reference" or when your arguments need to be objects.... you'll also have the `$user` and `$archived` variables set (and using memory) in the caller after it has made the call, so an additional memory overhead as well

Comment: The second call is an assignation before the function call. The assignation stays out of the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question: There are no named parameters.

The example in my question simply assigns values to variables and then passes those variables to the function.

```
list_items( $user = 10, $archived = false );

// is same as this:
$user = 10;
$archived = false;
list_items( $user, $archived );
```